# Google app engine(python) ImportError: No module named oauth2 in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth-2.0

I have used python twitter script from http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/
and oauth2 from https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Comment: pls accept Wooble's answer, it is correct

Answer (score 4):

To import third-party modules in App Engine, they need to be included (or symlinked) in the project directory. Your regular PYTHONPATH isn't checked, as modules installed on your local machine most likely won't be available on the production servers.