# ImportError: No module named oauth2client

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, importerror, google-signin

I'm following instructions in the Google Sign-In for Android documentation (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) and am trying to implement the token verification in my Python code.

I am developing on local host. For some reason, I am getting this error when I try this import `from oauth2client import client, crypt` into my Google App Engine backend, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client`
```

I've installed oauth2 using sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python
(https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation). The installation log shows:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: google-api-python-client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_api_python_client-1.5.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: httplib2>=0.8,<1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Downloading/unpacking oauth2client>=2.0.0,<3 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/oauth2client/oauth2client-2.0.0.post1.tar.gz#md5=6309e12fe2bc0f038708e2c9ec4b1f69 (from google-api-python-client)
Downloading oauth2client-2.0.0.post1.tar.gz (66kB): 66kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/oauth2client/setup.py) egg_info for package oauth2client
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests'
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.6.1,<2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already up-to-date: uritemplate>=0.6,<1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client>=2.0.0,<3->google-api-python-client)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client>=2.0.0,<3->google-api-python-client)
Requirement already up-to-date: rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client>=2.0.0,<3->google-api-python-client)
Requirement already up-to-date: simplejson>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from uritemplate>=0.6,<1->google-api-python-client)
Installing collected packages: oauth2client
Found existing installation: oauth2client 2.0.0-post1
Uninstalling oauth2client:
Successfully uninstalled oauth2client
Running setup.py install for oauth2client
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests'
Successfully installed oauth2client
```

I see that someone has provided an answer, but I don't know how to do this symlink that is described here: the [Google app engine(python) ImportError: No module named oauth2 in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403000/google-app-enginepython-importerror-no-module-named-oauth2-in-google-app-engi)

I'm thinking this has something to do with the path, but I have no idea how to set it so that oauth2client is installed globally. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a VM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out this documentation from Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring for installing third-party packages to the application.

As per the instructions, I created a folder called 'lib' inside my project folder, and created a file called appengine_config.py, also inside my project folder.

In appengine_config.py file, I entered the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

Then, on my terminal while inside my project folder, I entered `sudo pip install -t lib google-api-python-client`.

This worked! The import no longer throws the error.