# Weird issue with Python import in GAE while it works in terminal

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth2client

**from oauth2client import client, crypt**

While the above line works perfectly in ipython terminal on Mac OS. The same line shows error while running Google App Engine Project saying :
**ImportError: No module named oauth2client**

Anyone encountered the same issue and got it fixed?

Comment: Is the module installed above `lib/` folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named oauth2client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663508/importerror-no-module-named-oauth2client)