# How to prevent "ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client" on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

We are receiving an error:

> ImportError: No module named OAuth2Client

We have noticed scores of questions around this topic, many unanswered and at least one answer that describes the solution of copying over files from the Google App Engine SDK.

This approach, however, seems tedious because all the dependencies are unclear. If we copy over `oauth2client` then run, the next error is another module that is missing. Fix that, then another module is missing, etc., etc.

What is ironic is that we can see all the files and modules needed, listed from Google App Engine SDK right in PyCharm but they seem inaccessible to the script.

Is there no better way to pull in all the files that `oauth2client` needs for Python to work on App Engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to "vendor" in the file(s).

We found a quick way to solve this based on this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring
and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663508/importerror-no-module-named-oauth2client).

1. Create a new folder called "**lib**" in the same folder as your app.yaml file. (You can name it something else. Just use that name below.)
2. Create an empty file called **appengine_config.py** in the same folder as your app.yaml file
3. Add two lines to that appengine_config.py file:

   `from google.appengine.ext import vendor
   vendor.add('lib')`
4. From terminal, navigate to the directory which contains that file and execute the following command:

   `sudo pip install -t lib google-api-python-client`

The import error will disappear and you will have all the sub-dependent modules as well.

Answer (score 88):

I have this problem and solved by installing `oauth2client` with `pip3`:

```
pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I also had the import error. Solved it by putting the following in the Command Prompt
    pip install --upgrade oauth2client

Comment: Don't use pip's --user option or if will install to the wrong place. Especailly if you plan to deploy an app. Create and Activate a virtual env, then install it and check that oauth2client exists under (venv)/Lib/site-packages.

Answer (score 51):

As per the `google-api-python` [documentation](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/master/drive/driveapp/README.md#step-2-install-the-google-client-library), try this

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client oauth2client
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me, running Jeremy Blythe's Motion Uploader on Raspbian 8.

Comment: It's confusing that https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth says: "The oauth2client library is included with the Google APIs Client Library for Python." ...

Answer (score 0):

Install [WHL file](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/#files)

```
pip install oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this

sudo python -m pip install oauth2client

Comment: using `sudo pip` is really a bad idea. you are messing up your whole system package manager. please don't do this.