# ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client in Gcloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I wanted to deploy my app engine to use machine learning engine in Gcloud with the following code:
https://github.com/novinfard/temp

I encountered a strange error as follows:

```
ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client
```

However this library have already installed in app engine, as the following upgrade command return that everything is updated:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

I applied the 'vendor' solutions as described here as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011777/3477974

But this does not work either.

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: `pip install -t lib ...` (from your app dir, where the app's `lib` directory exists) not `pip install ...` (and you don't need sudo for that)

Comment: by "from your app dir", you mean on gcloud on server, like active shell?

Comment: No, your app code dir, where your `app.yaml` file exists.

Comment: I used the same command, the github repo shows it

Answer (score 1):

As of version `1.7.0` of `google-api-python-client` the hard requirement for `oauth2client` has been dropped. I.e. it will not be included when installing the `google-api-python-client`.

You can fix this by manually installing `oauth2client` in your vendor folder.

```
$ pip install -t <vendor_folder> oauth2client
```

---

> This release drops the hard requirement on oauth2client and installs
>   google-auth by default instead. oauth2client is still supported but will
>   need to be explicitly installed.

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/releases/tag/v1.7.0