# Why is using sudo pip a bad idea?

Tags: python, pip

In a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574741/10831408) I was reviewing recently, I read that it's advised not to use 'sudo pip' to install certain items. Can someone clarify why this is and what the downsides/upsides are? Thanks!

Comment: It’s generally a good idea to operate with the least privileges necessary, and you shouldn’t need root access to install a bunch of Python packages. This may also mean you’d need to run all Python scripts requiring those packages as root, depending on how the permissions are set, which is surely a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your OS has a Python interpreter to run Python software *controlled by your package manager*, be it apt, yum, or App Store. Any Python package installed to the system Python installation are dependencies of such software, or that software itself.

By installing or updating packages in your system Python, you can *break that software*. Also, your modifications would be overwritten with the next update of something that required a dependency you've overwritten ("upgraded"), which often occurs when you install something with many dependencies. This can bite you at the most inopportune moment.

If you value your time and sanity, *always* use `virtualenv` or your favorite wrapper over it. Preferably have one virtualenv per project, and separate virtualenvs for stuff like AWS CLI.  *Never* `sudo pip install` anything for your development.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo <anything>` is a bad idea because it requires root password/privilege.

Especially when it is not needed.

You may have a rogue pip script sitting somewhere in your path, for example, that can break your system.